# Port forwarding issues

Tags: routing

I have a home web server that is behind a Linksys E1200 router and Verizon Westell modem.  To access the web server from outside, I forwarded the data though both devices.  The method is working for SSH, but not HTTP.  The server is working perfectly (I can navigate right to the server from any local device), but I'm unable to access it from outside.  The same method has worked in the past.

Comment: What settings have you performed on the router? Does the webhost accept incoming connections from locations other than the local network?

Comment: @canadmos Generic port forwarding (port 80 to port 80).  I'm running Apache HTTPD 2.2.15 on Oracle Linux.  Apache is configured to accept all inbound connections on port 80 (LISTEN *:80).

Comment: Assuming you used the same procedure to forward both, changing the ports as necessary, then maybe your ISP is blocking port 80 from the outside. Some ISPs forbid running a server in their TOS and enforce it by blocking some common server ports.

Comment: You may try, just to check what Synetech suggested, to forward port 22  (which we know is not blocked) to port 80 of your Apache server. Now you try to contact with a Browser http://your.home.address:22 and see whether this replies. If it does, it is your ISP's fault, and you will have to start thinking about a hosting service.

Comment: I'll check, thanks.  That sucks, why the heck would my ISP block me from making my own web server?

Comment: I rerouted SSH through port 80 on the modem, and that failed.  I guess Verizon is blocking it.

Comment: I can't imagine they block port 22 AND 80. (Or maybe they are blocking everything below port 1024. If you want to know for sure you could try forwarding port 50888 (just a random port) to port 80. If that also fails (connecting to `http://your_public_ip:50888`) you are doing something wrong (and Verizon might not be blocking 22 and 80 at all).

Comment: @Rik Port 22 works fine, port 80 is the only one with problems.  Thanks for the advice, I'll try to use a random port to test it.

Comment: If 22 works you could also try port 8080. It's often used as an alternative to 80. If that isn't blocked it may look nicer to use that. `http://my_public_ip:8080`